# GTM fires my tag in debug mode only. In Live mode it works on Chrome only

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a GTM container which has 2 tags ,

1. 'Setup tag' which is triggered on All-Page view  , calculates somethings and then triggers an event.
2. 'Sender tag' which is triggered by the event created above , and sends calculated value to Google analytics.

GTM works perfectly in debug/preview mode for all three browsers {chrome, safari, firefox }.
However when I publish the container , GTM works only if I use Chrome. 
Container is published, cache is cleared , CookieDomain is set to auto... 
Am I doing something wrong?

[image]
[image: First tag initial code is like this]

Comment: Not an answer, but I don't see the point - GTM already has a window loaded event, which  is equivalent to window.onload, so you can simply remove your event handler as a potential point of failure.

Comment: thanks @EikePierstorff ! That was actually the issue !!! I will update the ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eike Pierstorff the issue is fixed. window.load in the script was the actual problem. This is how everything looks like now :

[image]
[image]